# Duplications on New Code not showing

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am using sonarqube Version 6.3.1 (build 21392).

The project baseline has code duplication of 12.2% when I run the report on newly added/modified code,

Sonar shows Duplications on New Code as ---------------  (blank ) total code duplication is increased from 12.2% to 15%, why sonar is not showing the Duplications on New Code.

When I have manually checked  2 new  files are having around 560 lines of duplicate (There are more files like this)

Thanks,
Sudharshan

Comment: Does it show _any_ values on new code? Have you disabled the SCM Sensor?

Comment: it doesn't show any value in new code, Yes i have disabled SCM Sensor

Comment: I tried both enabling and disabling SCM Sensor. However, I can see Bugs and Code smell is shown for new code

Comment: ERROR: Unable to TFS annotate the project which raised the following authentication exception: TF31002: Unable to connect to this Team Foundation Server: https://yourdomain.com/tfs/Latest/Sources/Prj1

Comment: I have used below pliugin and it works fine https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-scm-tfvc

Answer (score 0):

I have used below pliugin and it works fine https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-scm-tfvc